# Find 近科全题新策法程 By 劉坦之

Tags: reference-materials

Can anyone help me find 近科全题新策法程 By 劉坦之?This is a work aimed at candidates of Qing imperial examinations.

It seems that it is also contained within 北京市文物局图书资料中心藏古籍珍本丛刊, but the latter work is much larger and apparently very expensive, making it seem unlikely to be found on the internet.

Comment: its term of use stated “Anytime, anywhere, **freely**, you can search the descriptions and view, print, or **download digitized images** of the holdings via the Internet”, well, maybe, . . . ask for help in japanese stackexchange?

Comment: Oh, good idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

the national archives of japan has this book, in 4 volumes:

[近科全題新策法程](https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/meta/result?IS_STYLE=default&IS_KIND=hierarchy&IS_NUMBER=100&IS_START=1&IS_TAG_S51=prnid&IS_KEY_S51=F1000000000000106718&IS_EXTSCH=F2009121017025600406%2BF2005031812174403109%2BF2008112110372321714%2BF1000000000000106718&IS_ORG_ID=F1000000000000106718&LIST_TYPE=default&IS_SORT_FLD=sort.tror%2Csort.refc&IS_SORT_KND=asc&DB_ID=G9100001EXTERNAL&DEF_XSL=default)

and, it’s “use restriction classification” is **open**

maybe, find a japanese colleague to help you to get it

have fun :)